# Add <select> element with data from MySQL to form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, load

I'm trying to create a form with `<select>` elements that is created dynamically based on jQuery's `.change` function. I want to have three `<select elements>` with option values changing based on what the user selected in the previous element.

I have this code.

**students.php:**

```
<form action='../insert.php' method='post' name='add_student'>

<!-- This is generated by PHP -->

<select id='add_student_customer'>
    <option>Select one...</option>
    <option value='1'>First value</option>
    <option value='2'>Second value</option>
    <option value='3'>Third value</option>
</select>

<!-- Here a select element will load from another PHP-file based on values from the previous select -->
<div id='add_student_contactperson_container'></div>

<!-- This is generated on page load but will not be visible until we select something in the previous select -->
<select id='add_student_course'>
  <option>Select something...</option>
  <option value='1'>An option</option>
  <option value='2'>A second option</option>
</select>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#add_student_course").hide()
$("#add_student_customer").change (function(){
    var row_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/load_customer_contacts.php",
        data: { 'customer_id':row_id },
        success: function(data){
            $("#add_student_contactperson_container").html(data);
        }
    });
});

$("#add_student_contact").change(function() {
    $("#add_student_course").show();
  });
});

</script>
```

However the `$("#add_student_course").show();` event wont work. Any ideas why? Also I wonder, will I be able to use the `<select>`-id that is loaded from `load_customer_contacts.php"` to my `<form>`? Will it follow even though its loaded *after* the page load?

Comment: Where is the element with id `add_student_course` defined?

Comment: @DvirAzulay is `add_student_course` a variable or function to be defined?

Answer (score 2):

Are you are expecting `#add_student_contact` to be loaded from the ajax?

If so then you need to register your event a different way so it works for elements that are added to the DOM post-initialisation, like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#add_student_contact", function(){
   $("#add_student_course").show();
});
```

I went for this above approach rather than `$("#add_student_contact").on` because I had issues with this recently. I am not sure the exact reason, it may not apply here, but I just know I had to do it on the `document` in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: When attaching events through class selectors your solutions may be better performance wise.

Comment: Hello and thank's for your comment. That did not really solve my problem because the `$(document).on("change", function()` fires on my first select change, I want it to fire only after my second. Also do you have any idea on my second question? Will the ID be able to use to my form?

Comment: @David, I change my answer slightly. And no I am not sure about your second question sorry

Comment: Thank you, the first part is working now. However the id did not follow on the POST as I expected.... I guess I have some googleing in front of me. Thank's anyway

Comment: Doesn't POST data work based on the `name` attribute? rather than the ID... I may be wrong but might be worth a try ;)

Comment: @musefan yes, and my select is generated by php with a `name` but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @David: Sorry, can't help anymore than that, not had to do this before. Usually when I do dynamic html like this I end up submitting the data via an AJAX query anyway

Answer (score 2):

On dynamically loaded things you need to attache the even using [jQuery.On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

It looks like your `#add_student_contact` is added dynamically.

```
$("#add_student_contact").on('change',(function() {
  $("#add_student_course").show();
});
```

Regarding your second question: The `load_customer_contacts.php` is loaded throught and AJAX call. This will not reload your page and if your data returned from the php routines is valid html it should show in your form